# No ImageView/ImageButton in Material Components (Android)

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

So I have styled my android app with material components but didn't found any replacement for ImageView and/or ImageButton.

Comment: You can use [MaterialButton](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons/) for ImageButton

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir How?

Answer (score 1):

About the `ImageView` you can use the **`ShapeableImageView`** which extends the `AppCompatImageView`.

You can use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/customImageViewRounded"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/...."
```

with:

```
  <style name="customImageViewRounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">32dp</item>

    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently in v1.1.0, there's no `MaterialImageView` or `MaterialImageButton`.

But in v1.2.0, there's [`ShapeableImageView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView.java) coming out which extends `AppCompatImageView`

Comment: Ok will look into it. Thanks.